# Why are my flask RESTplus models not registered

Tags: python, api, flask, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I have a Flask RESTplus code where I instantiated models in my "models.py" folder.
I named all API models inside their respective Flask SQLAlchemy model classes

For instance

```
class User(db.Model):
   serializer = api.model("user", {
      "name" : fields.String,
   })
   name = db.Column(db.String(10))

class Profile(db.Model):
   serializer = api.model("profile",{
      "country": fields.String,
   })
   country = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

Like that for each model, using Flask app factory approach, and namespaces for the API.
My problem is, only one model shows up in the Swagger UI, and I'm so confused.
I've tried everything to make the others show, but nothing has worked

The code is live on Heroku so you can see the Swagger UI there

https://restplus-music-review.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.
The problem was from me not using the `api.marshal_with` decorator on any method. But I happened to use the `model` parameter on a response decorator. Which caused that one model to be documented, and not the others. Thanks